# Django-Social-Auth force user grant permission

Tags: django, facebook, django-socialauth

I'm create and facebook app that must require **publish_stream** to publish some information on user's wall. But when user interact with auth dialog they have an option skipping publish on your wall with your behave. So I have to ask if Django-Social-Auth support to check for permission I want, If user reject it, reopen auth dialog so user can grant it.
I've already put publish_stream in facebook extend permissions settings.

Comment: If user rejects the permission, it means the user doesn't want your app to publish anything. Why'd you ask again?

Comment: Ask again how, how to do that with django - social auth. I just call /login/facebook/ and user logged in auto

Comment: The only way is to log user out and ask him to login again with the same permission. But it's not ethical. Facebook API itself says `Do not re-prompt for permissions continually`.